# Symfony2 Forms - Dependent entity fields

Tags: forms, symfony

Relating to a cars application, I have a form where the user can choose brand and model ; the aim is that the model depends on the brand. For example, when you choose "Brand A", then only models related to brand A are displayed.

For now, I am already blocked on the initial form (where no data is set) ; there is a default brand displayed, and I would like models relative to this brand being displayed.

I followed some tutorials to add an event subscriber, but I can't make it works ; I am unable to get brand's field value into my subscriber... I tryed to get the Brand entity, but logically it is empty (because the form has not been submitted).

Anybody has an idea ?

FormType :

```
public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {

    $builder->add( 'brand', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Brand',
        'property' => 'name',
    ));

    $builder->add( 'model', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'MyBundle:Model',
        'property' => 'name',   
    ));


    /* Add event for the first model choices */
    $builder->addEventSubscriber( new ModelChoicesSubscriber() );
}
```

FormSubscriber :

```
class ModelChoicesSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {

        return array( FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA => 'preSetData' );
    }

    public function preSetData( FormEvent $event ) {
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();

        if( $data == null ) {
            return;
        }

        $brand = $form->get( 'brand' );
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want to be able to access the entities when the form is being created with an non-existing entity?

Comment: Hum.. When the form is created, the entities are created, nop ?
Whatever, what I want to do is to access the brand select value, in order to display the right model by default

Comment: The support of dependent fields in Symfony is still heavily discussed: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/5807 - Cross your fingers!